# How to know whether a paused DAG exists in composer airflow or not?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, gcloud, google-cloud-composer

After uploading a file through GCP command to DAG folder, I would like to check whether a DAG is created or not. May I know the command to check whether a paused DAG was created or not? In this question I have mentioned "Pause DAG" as I am using "core-dags_are_paused_at_creation=true" configuration.

There is load_dags but it only returns non paused DAGs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your question, you can simply query to retrieve a list with all paused DAGs, using the ***is_paused*** [method](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/index.html#airflow.models.DAG.is_paused), as follows:

```
airflow=# select * from dag where is_paused;
```

Besides, according to the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli.html#list_dags) you can list you DAGs with the below command:

```
airflow list_dags [-h] [-sd SUBDIR] [-r]
```

> **Named Arguments**
>
> *-sd, --subdir*
>   : File location or directory from which to look for the dag. 
>   Defaults to ‘**[AIRFLOW_HOME]/dags**’ where [AIRFLOW_HOME] is the value you set for ‘AIRFLOW_HOME’ config you set in ‘airflow.cfg’
>
> Default: “[AIRFLOW_HOME]/dags”
>
> *-r, --report*
>   : Show DagBag loading report
>
> Default: False

Comment: I am using Google cloud platform's Composer. -r is not an attribute for list_dags command. I am not sure select statement will work or not but do you know how I can run it in shell script?

Comment: You can use `-r`, you just have to make sure it's escaped, so it isn't passed to `gcloud`. It would be something like `gcloud composer environments run $ENV run list_dags -- --report`.

Comment: @SantoshVysyaraju, if you want to use the commands using composer you have to follow the following syntax: _gcloud composer environments run ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
    --location LOCATION SUBCOMMAND_ . Regarding the select statement in a Composer Shell, I am digging deeper on it and I will get back to you. Link: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/accessing/airflow-cli#running_airflow_cli_commands

Comment: @SantoshVysyaraju, you are right you can not query in a shell script with only composer. However, according to the documentation you can use Cloud SDK to have access to gcloud commands [1]. In addition, the method _is_paused_ is only used in airflow. Link [1]: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/ . Let me know if it helps so I can update the answer or look for another solution.